# Tkinter button 'not defined' when ran

Tags: python-2.7, button, tkinter

I am following a quick guide online to start using Tk in Python (2.7) and so far, I have this code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Note Taker")

root.mainloop()

button1 = Button(root, text="button1", command = Button1)
button2 = Button(root, text="button2", command = Button2)
button3 = Button(root, text="button3", command = Button3)


text = Entry(root)
listbox = Listbox(root)


text.pack()
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
button3.pack()
listbox.pack()


def Button1():
    listbox.insert(END, "button1 pressed")

def Button2():
    listbox.insert(END, "button2 pressed")

def Button3():
    text_contents = text.get()
    listbox.insert(END, text_contents)
    text.delete(0,END)
```

However when I run this, the GUI is loaded, however none of the buttons are shown, instead I am given this 'NameError':

```
button1 = Button(root, text="button1", command = Button1)
NameError: name 'Button1' is not defined
```

I'm sure its purely my error however what could be changed to make this run correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move

```
def Button1():
    listbox.insert(END, "button1 pressed")
```

before

```
button1 = Button(root, text="button1", command=Button1)
```

since `command = Button1` references `Button1`.

And of course, do the same for `Button2` and `Button3`.

---

Also move

```
root.mainloop()
```

to the bottom of the script, so the flow of control does not get caught in the event loop before the Tkinter widgets are defined.

---

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Note Taker")


def Button1():
    listbox.insert(END, "button1 pressed")


def Button2():
    listbox.insert(END, "button2 pressed")


def Button3():
    text_contents = text.get()
    listbox.insert(END, text_contents)
    text.delete(0, END)


button1 = Button(root, text="button1", command=Button1)
button2 = Button(root, text="button2", command=Button2)
button3 = Button(root, text="button3", command=Button3)

text = Entry(root)
listbox = Listbox(root)

text.pack()
button1.pack()
button2.pack()
button3.pack()
listbox.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah it was just me being stupid, :P still learning.

Comment: Works perfectly :) Nice one.